# Error building wheels for collected packages: cvxopt

Tags: python, visual-studio

I trying to install cvxopt but I am facing the following error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'm.lib'
error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.37.32822\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1181.
```

From what I gathered from the internet I need to `MSVC: set this variable to 1 if compiling with MSVC 14 or later`. I believe I also read this can be done in setup.py. The trouble I am having is I am completely new to python development, so I am not sure how to do this. So my question is how can I set MSVC to 1?